# Why does unboxing cast to the concrete class rather than Number

Tags: java

For example unboxing Integer results in a cast to Integer followed by a call to intValue(). Why not simply cast to Number followed by the necessary intValue() to get the primitive ? Naturally the question extends to unboxing all the other wrappers.

Comment: You have over 100 questions without an accepted answer. I would hope this is not fire-and-forget messaging ;)

Comment: pl that's because they have not been answered, you can see that for yourseltef.

Comment: Perhaps there is something to be learnt from asking so many questions which don't have an acceptable answer. ;)

Comment: If you use generics and unboxing you wouldn't need to either cast it Integer or Number, nor would you need to call intValue(). Can you clarify why you would do this and what problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Java did what you propose, that would break the very important feature that boxing/unboxing causes no precision loss. There is already an established principle in Java that any precision-losing conversion must be explicitly asked for with a cast operator. It is illegal to write

```
final int i = 1L;
```

so it would be wrong if this worked:

```
final int i = Long.valueOf(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I notice that Integer is final. When invoking intValue on an expression of type (reference to) Integer, there is no need to check whether the instance type overrides intValue. That would be necessary for an expression of type (reference to) Number.